# Как получить PHP массив с JSON

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

как получить массив как на фото
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$dbconnection=new PDO ("mysql::host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", 
 $username, $password);

 $row=$dbconnection->prepare ("select * from  telo");

 $row->execute();

 $data=array();


 foreach ($row as $result)
 {
 $isonformat ['id']=$result['id'];

 $isonformat ['title']=$result['title'];

 array_push ($data, $isonformat);

 echo  json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT), "\n";
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте лучше так:

данные закидывайте в массив с названием `$movies`, а потом эту переменную закиньте в `$data` с ключом `movies`

```
$data['movies'] = $movies;
```

либо сразу в `data` сделать этот ключ и инициализировать как массив. И уже туда пушить `$data['movies'] = [];`

Comment: Удалил $data=array(); и добавил $data['movies'] = $movies; 
Вот что получилось
 {"movies":null,"0":{"id":"1","title":"Star Wars"}} {"movies":null,"0":{"id":"1","title":"Star Wars"},"1":{"id":"2","title":"Back to the Future"}}


а как получить   вот ток  json { "movies":[ { "id":"1",  "title":"Star Wars"} , {"id":"2", "title":"Back to the Future"} ]   }

Спасибо за ответ))

Comment: Нет, вы не так сделали значит. то, что вы показываете может быть только в одном случае, если movies вы вставляете в цикле . и почему у вас два раза элемент со star wars?

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> $isonformat
> ```

Не хватает инициализации, поэтому в массиве всё одно и то же.

> ```
> json_encode($data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)
> ```

Флаг выкинь.

Comment: Ну и за что минус?